# Windows 10 creators update bluetooth weird behaviour

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, bluetooth, connection, windows-10-v1703

I have a Asus bt gamepad (TV500BG) and it works perfectly fine with older windows 10 devices and Android devices.

It gives visual feedback using lights for

1. searching for devices
2. discoverable and ready to pair and
3. connected

However on windows 10 with creators update, the system shows its paired or connected, however the gamepad has not originally connected (no visual feedback seen on gamepad)

When on stage `2`, I can see the device on windows but if I click `Pair`, it shows setup progress and shows `Paired` (and not connected which it should) and gamepad continues to be in stage `2`.

Once paired already and if gamepad is switched on, it goes to stage `1` searching for active paired hosts to connect with. As soon as I switch on, windows immediately shows `connected` which was before `paired` when inactive, however gamepad continues to be in stage `1`.

This happens only in creators update, and I have a feeling that the protocols have been updated such that it updates properly to incoming data but failing to send parsable data to slaves.

**What can I do about it? How do I troubleshoot?**

---

**Update**: I find the same behavior of creators update with other bluetooth slaves including bluetooth headphones and other even watches :/

**Update 2**: Mine is an Intel Bluetooth Adapter, NOT Realtek or Broadcomm as I can see some articles explaining issues with Bluetooth manufactured by the above two.